# How can I find start and end occurrence of character in Python

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, shift, find-occurrences

I have a dataframe `df` with the following ids (in `Col`). 
The last occurrence of A/B/C represents the start, and the last occurrence of X is the end. I should ignore any other A,B,C between start and end (e.g. rows 8 and 9).

I have to find start and end records from this data and assign a number to each of these occurrences. The column `count` is my desired output:

```
    Col         ID
    P
    Q
    A             
    A              
    A             1
    Q             1 
    Q             1 
    B             1 
    C             1
    S             1 
    S             1
    X             1
    X             1  
    X             1 
    Q
    Q
    R
    R
    C              
    C             2 
    D             2 
    E             2 
    B             2 
    K             2 
    D             2 
    E             2 
    E             2 
    X             2 
    X             2
```

This code:

```
lc1 = df.index[df.Col.eq('A') & df.Col.ne(df.Col.shift(-1))]
```

would give me an array of all the last occurrences of Index values of 'A', in this case `[5]`.

```
lc1 = df.index[df.Col.eq('C') & df.Col.ne(df.Col.shift(-1))]  # [20]
lc2 = df.index[df.Col.eq('X') & df.Col.ne(df.Col.shift(-1))]  # [14,29]
```

I would use `iloc` to print the count values:

```
df.iloc[5:14]['count'] = 1
df.iloc[20:29]['count'] = 2
```

How can I find the indices of A/B/C together and print the count values of each start and end occurrence?

Comment: Can someone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find your indices of A, B, and C you can do:

```
df[(df.Col =='A')|(df.Col =='B')|(df.Col =='C')].index
```

Print your start counts:

```
df1 = df[df['count'] != df['count'].shift(+1)]
print df1[df1['count'] != 0]['count']
```

Print your end counts:

```
df2 = df[df['count'] != df['count'].shift(-1)]
print df2[df2['count'] != 0]['count']
```

On a sidenote, calling a column `count` is a bad idea because `count` is a method of the DataFrame and then you get ambiguity when doing `df.count`.

EDIT: Corrected since I was answering to a wrong question.

Comment: Thank you Khris !! Sorry for the confusion. "count" is what I want to have as an output column in dataframe - I changed it to "ID"